# Evaluate : $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{0}\frac{dxdy}{1+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate  $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{0}\frac{dxdy}{1+x^2+y^2}$

This is my steps :

$\displaystyle\begin{align*}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{0}\frac{dxdy}{1+x^2+y^2}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-1}^{0}\frac{r}{1+r^2}drd\theta\end{align*}$

Is that right?

Comment: To understand the polar domain, draw a picture of the (x,y) domain of integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the domain is the half of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ to the left of the y-axis and do a transformation to polar coordinates

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^0 \frac{dxdy}{1+x^2+y^2}=
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \int_0^1 \frac{rdrd\theta}{1 + r^2}=
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_0^1 \frac{rdr}{1+r^2}=
\pi \int_0^1 \frac{rdr}{1+r^2} 
$$

From trig substitution
$$
\pi \frac{1}{2} \ln(r^2+1)|_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. May I ask one more question ?? Why do you consider the left of the y-axis ???

Comment: Draw a picture (third time).

Comment: since x goes from $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to zero we know the domain is contained in the left half of the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$. Since y goes from -1 to 1 we know it is the entire left half.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: change to polar coordinates.

Comment: I tried to change to polar coordinates!!But I don't know how to change the upper and lower limit

Comment: Draw a picture.